# Can a Wilcoxon signed rank test be applied on dated data?

Tags: statistical-significance, inference, paired-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have data for military male and female orders for types of clothing purchased from 2012 to 2018 (below is a very simple example - most of the data is one item purchases). If I look at one type of clothing, say a pair of shoes, I could have 10,000 data values for men and 6,000 values for women (as there are more men than women in the data set). I need to know if the usage patterns differ across the different types of clothing and footwear.

Can I run the test over all years or do I need to do it year by year?  Also, is this considered paired data, even though the military members have to buy the clothing and footwear as part of their uniform?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you've provided enough context for anyone to answer your questions meaningfully. Either of the tests you describe are possible from a procedural perspective, but what would it mean? Providing more detail on the underlying variables will increase the chance that your question is answered.

Comment: I have data for male and female orders for types of clothing purchased from 2012 to 2018.  If I look at one type of clothing, say a pair of shoes, I could have 10K data values for men and 6K values for women (as there are more men than women in the data set).  I need to know if the usage patterns differ across the different types of clothing and footwear.

Comment: That's great context. You should edit that into your question directly. You should also discuss why you think that the data might be paired. It seems like these are many independent choices by consumers. Also, why does your example list such low numbers (if I am correctly interpreting 10K to mean 10000)? Very different tests might be appropriate in that case.

Comment: To me "usage patterns" isn't clear.  Just looking at shoes, you don't want to compare the total male orders to the total female orders because you have more men than women in your sample. Would it make sense to arrange the counts in a contingency table where you have two columns, male and female, and then several rows, shoes, shirts, and so on, and look at the relative proportions for each?

Comment: By usage patterns I mean do men use up shoes faster than women and may have to order more over time.  It's all about how to facilitate clothing demands based on gender.  Are they different between men and women.

Comment: It sounds like you would need to know the total number of potential male customers and female customers, and calculate a rate (e.g. shoe orders per man) (?)

Comment: Sal, are you telling me that a Wilcoxon test can't be used on my data?  Because of the different lengths I'm assuming an unpaired test (Mann-Whitney) would be proper.